# C# - Check TCP/IP socket status from client side

Tags: c#, tcp, connection, client-server, polling

I'd like to provide my TCP/IP client class with a CheckConnection function so that I can check if something wrong has happened (my own client disconnected, server disconnected, server stuck up,...).
I have something like that:

```
bool isConnectionActive = false;
if (Client.Poll(100000, SelectMode.SelectWrite) == true)
  isConnectionActive = true;
```

based on what MSDN says:

> SelectWrite: true, if processing a Connect(EndPoint), and the connection has succeeded; -or- true if data can be sent; otherwise, returns false.

The point is that, testing this with simple server application, I am getting always true from CheckConnection, even if server-listener has been closed and even if server-application has been shutdown; that's weird, because I expect in those cases that both no connection is being processed (already connected minutes ago) and no data can be sent.

I have already implemented a similar connection check on server side using a combination of Poll with SelectRead and Available and it seems working properly; so now, should I write something similar also on client side? is the SelectWrite approach correct (but I'm using it improperly)?

Comment: Based on web/test findings, it seems TCP/IP hasn't any kind of ToClient/ToServer notification when a connection is closed ByServer/ByClient; this is also testified by the fact that if you call for `TcpClient.Close()` on server side, the client on its side is still able to call for `Client.Socket.Send(byte[] buffer)` without getting any error/exception, conversely any call for `Client.Socket.Receive(byte[] buffer)` would result in SocketException. Hence, I would conclude that the check based on the {Poll with SelectRead + Available} as I've done for server class is the only way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of things you can check but none of them are assured to give you the result you are looking for.  Even the implementation you have on the server will not work 100% of the time.  I guarantee it will fail one day.

There are FIN packets, which should be sent from the client to the server, and vice versa when a connection is closed, but there is no guarantee that these will be delivered, or even processed.

This is generally known as the [TCP Half Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_half-open) problem.

Closing a TCP Socket is a mutually agreed process, you generally have a messaging protocol which tells the other end that it's closing, or you have some predefined set of instructions and you close after that.

The only reliable way to 100% detect if a remote socket is closed is to send some data to it.  Only if you get an error back will you know if the socket has closed.

Some applications which don't send a lot of data implement a keep-alive protocol, they simply send/receive a few bytes every minute, so they know that the remote endpoint is present.

You can technically have two servers that are in a connected state and haven't sent data to each other for 10 years.  Each end continues to believe that the other end is there until one try's to send some data and finds out it isn't.

Comment: let me add one additional detail from some tests I ran: after the actual disconnection of the server, the client (`System.Net.Sockets`) can call for Send function once without getting exceptions/errors, then on second call for Send function a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` is thrown. So I would conclude: for disconnection check always do multiple sendings.

Comment: Yes. After you do a send you are done with the socket.  There is no facility for the socket to return an error to you.  Meanwhile the OS is packaging your buffer, putting it on the wire, the network is transmitting it, the OS is waiting for a response, finally the OS gets no response and marks the socket as faulty.  During this time you could of sent megabytes of data and called send 100's of times depending on the characteristics of the socket.  This is why your application needs a messaging protocol.  Otherwise you have no way of knowing that the message you sent was received.