# Find out that the client has disconnected C# TcpClient

Tags: c#, tcp, stream, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am developing a server using TcpClient / TcpListener.

The server keeps a list of all streams for all connected clients.
Please tell me if one of the clients forcibly disconnects or closes the application, how can I find out? I need to understand that the client has disconnected. How to do it?

As far as I know, there is no such method in the TcpClent class. What should I do?

Do you need to create a cycle in which some data will be sent to each client and, if the client does not respond, delete it?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59964679/c-sharp-check-tcp-ip-socket-status-from-client-side/60013356#60013356

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - Check TCP/IP socket status from client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59964679/c-sharp-check-tcp-ip-socket-status-from-client-side)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect this if the client is not disconnected gracefully. then the only option is left to poll continuously after a certain interval.

Comment: "left to poll continuously after a certain interval" - tell me which request is better to send?